# Install pandas in ABAQUS 6.14 python environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, abaqus

What I am trying to do is to install the Pandas package in the python distribution that comes within the ABAQUS CAE package.

`Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct  4 2012, 15:15:08) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

The main problem that I am facing is to get an old version of numpy `(1.8.2 max),` because pandas require `numpy >= 1.7.2` but ABAQUS also requires the  multiarray packages discontinued after the version `numpy 1.9.0`.

I managed to install pip in the python environment but when trying to obtain any of these old versions of `numpy (1.7.0 - 1.8.2)` it crashes as there is no x64 available modules on the repo. Here is the error code given.

```
   Rolling back uninstall of numpy 
Command "C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.14-3\tools\SMApy\python2.7\python.exe -u -c
 "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\cris\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-gcrgtg\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
 'exec'))" install --record
 c:\users\cris\appdata\local\temp\pip-xjzhpa-record\install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\cris\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gcrgtg\numpy\
```

I have successfully run a x64 Python environment with a `numpy 1.7.0` package obtained throug `conda`. But I was unsuccessful trying to apply that methodology to the Python environment embedded in ABAQUS.

Then, how could I install an old version of `numpy <= 1.8.2` in a x64 Python environment?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/38845741/1004168. Abaqus on its own doesn't use numpy at all, so i don't get that part of your issue.

Comment: I am extracting data from the .obd file generated from ABAQUS and I need to save it in a generic format (.csv). The package pandas is very handy for manipulate and store/read tabulated data. But the package requires numpy 1.7.0. And ABAQUS apparently needs to use modules inside the numpy library (multiarray)  because when removed the program does not start. And the support to that library have been removed after numpy 1.9.0.

Comment: I think you must have some plug in / add on / that's loading numpy.  Anyway, if you just want to export as csv there is the csv module.

Comment: From default installation, ABAQUS 6.14 exiges numpy to run. I am using the csv module but pandas would ease things. Thank you for your input.